# Getting first image from html using Python/Django

Tags: python, html, django, image

I am grabbing a bunch of html from a service and parsing it slightly.
I am looking for a way to grab the link from the first image tag.

Something similar like this JQuery code:

```
var imagelink = $('img:first', feed.content).attr('src');
```

But of course using only Python/Django (server runs on Google app engine). I rather not use any other libraries, just to grab a simple link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do any more parsing of html I probably will look into one of the libraries suggested. But for now I have solved this by:

```
   startImgPos = post.find('<img', 0, len(post)) + 4
    if(startImgPos > -1):
        endImgPos = post.find('>', startImgPos, len(post))
        imageTag = post[startImgPos:endImgPos]
        startSrcPos = imageTag.find('src="', 0, len(post)) +5
        endSrcPos = imageTag.find('"', startSrcPos , len(post)) 
        linkTag = imageTag[startSrcPos:endSrcPos]
        r['linktag'] = linkTag
```

I'll improve this later, but for now it does the trick. Feel free to suggest any more ideas/improvements to the above code.

Comment: Not sure why my own answer got ranked down. It was exactly what I was looking for at the time. A simple answer to find an img without the use of libraries.

Answer (score 9):

You can use BeautifulSoup to do this:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

It's a XML/HTML parser. So you pass in the raw html, and then you can search it for particular tags/attrs etc.

something like this should work:

```
tree = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
img_link = (tree.find('img')[0]).attr['src']
```

Comment: Good to know. Since its just for one link(src) I'm looking for a way without a library. Currently my python skills are not that great trying to search strings but currently learning...

Comment: even though it's only for one link in the file, there is a lot of HTML to parse through. You can try use Regular Expressions to find the first instance of <a href=..> but you will probably find that the BeautifulSoup approach is easiest

Comment: Not quite, you'd need to do index 0 on tree.find_all but for tree.find it will find the first one so index 0 would throw an error

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what I'm looking for. Actually, the real code is like this:

```
tree = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
img_link = tree.find_all('img')[0].get('src')
```

Works great! thanks timmy-omahony